# Two Textfield with single pickerview in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am new to IOS i want to display two textfield with single picker view programatically. i created two array for two different textfield but while running my picker view showing first array only and selecting pickerview both textfield changing.where i done wrong?

Done button action in picker view coding :

```
-(void)pickerDoneClicked

{
    NSLog(@"Done Clicked");

    [txtText resignFirstResponder];
    [currency1 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

picker view delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

{

    return 1;

}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    return arrMsg.count;
    return currencyname1.count;

}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    return [arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
    return [currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];

}


- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

Comment: use tags and based on tag, show the output

Comment: At a time only one value is return, this is your mistake, if you set the TextField tag or any check the condition to return particular value.